Failed to Scan - unable to connect to scanner - Ubuntu 24.04.1
I'm using an HP laser jet 1536 printer/scanner. On my 20 year old Dell Inspiron 1545 with Ubuntu 22.04.4 the scanner is recognized by "Document Scanner" and scans perfectly. I have since upgraded to a Dell Latitude 7490 with Ubuntu 24.04.1 pre-loaded. Now "Document Scanner" recognizes the HP Laser Jet 1536 but pressing the Scan button results in the message "Failed to Scan - unable to connect to scanner".
In past this error has occurred in older versions of Ubuntu and the fix is "sudo apt install sane-airscan ipp-usb". These are already included in Version 24.04.1. This is not a duplicate of the question  "Scanner doesn't work on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS". The model printer is different and there is no eSCL option in the drop down list. Nor is this an Apt vs Snap issue. I deleted and reinstalled Document Scanner (Simple Scan) using APT. It makes no difference.
HPLIP support level for the "HP Laser Jet M1536 DNF"  "FULL End of support. I don't really know if this presents a conflict with Ubuntu 24.04.1.
At this point I have tried all the suggested fixes. None have worked.
Document Scanner works on either computer using Ubuntu 22.04.4. It fails only when I use Ubuntu 24.04.1.
Added dual boot Ubuntu 22.04.5 to primary hard drive. Got same error as with 24.04.1. Any more ideas I can try?

This question is similar to: Scanner doesnt work on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I checked the question  "Scanner doesnt work on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. ". For my scanner there is no eSCL option in the drop down list. I checked the HPLIP support page and confirmed that HPLIP is installed. Also of note is that the support level for the "HP LaserJjet M1536 DNF" is "Full (end of Support)" This may {or may not} explain the problem I have encountered.

This question is similar to: Scanner not detected in simple-scan in Ubuntu 24.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. This is probably a snap issue. Switching to APT may fix it

Thanks, maybe installing Simple Scan using apt will make a difference. I already updated and upgraded using APT. No luck. I am using "Document Scanner" that was preloaded with Ubuntu 24.04.1 and the scanner model is different. If Simple Scan makes a difference I will edit appropriately.

Determine if your system can detect the errant scanner,
scanimage -L

@JPB Document Scanner is same as simple-scan. But the upgrade replaces apt app with the snap app, which has compatibility issues.

None of the "fixes" seem to make a difference. The scanner is recognized but works only as a printer. The HP Laser Jet m1536 DNF is at least 14 years old and no longer actively supported by HP. Others are looking for Windows 11 drivers. As much as I hate sending perfectly good hardware to the landfill, I will replace it when the ink cartridge expires and get a wifi enabled device.

By any chance, does it work with older version of Ubuntu?

Well thanks very much Archisman Panigrahi. Finally some progress. It works under Ubuntu 22.04.4 and I have amended the question to reflect that. Now what does that mean?

I booted the Dell Latitude 7490 (new laptop) via USB using the hard drive from the old Dell Inspiron 1545 with Ubuntu 22.04.4. The scanner scanned perfectly. So I don't think the new computer is the problem. i've edited the original question as appropriate.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.5 (as dual boot on primary hard drive) and Document Scanner produced the same error as Ubuntu 25.04.1. Not sure what to try next...

Do you mean, it works in 22.04.4 but fails in 22.04.5?

YES. Thanks for followup. As of this AM it now ~works in 22.04.5. With gparted I copied 22.04.4 from old SSD to UEFI drive. Spent all day trying to make it boot but failed. I deleted 22.04.5  and grub2core.img partitions. WTF now nothing on the UEFI drive booted. Went to bed. This AM I reinstalled 22.04.5 alongside existing OSes. Weirdly 22.04.4 got updated to 22.04.5 and all 3 partitions now boot from the UEFI drive. Document Scanner works from the copied partition. Kind of a backdoor method but it produced the best possible outcome. Now to try custom SW - JAVA, PYTHON and C++...

I got the scanner to magically work on all of our 12 ubuntu 24.04 computers at our local library by installing naps2. It works great and has a really nice interface. Simple scan could never find the scanner.
Now if I could only get something to work with the printers. HPLIP fails on 24.04 no matter what version I try. It installs from synaptic but doesn't work.
naps2 scanner deb link

Interesting that you're having a similar problem. I almost installed NAPS2 but the website doesn't list the HP m1536 in the list of supported scanners. It's an ~20 year old monochrome print/scan/fax. It works fine under Ubuntu 22.04. Ubuntu Version HPLIP VersionI noticed the version of HPLIP installed in 22.04 is 3.21.12 while the version of HPLIP installed

try it anyway our hp scanner is very old and bam it instantly worked after years of screwing with other apps
